# Function selecting a day and with second parameter u can add or reverse day in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function when selecting a day for example (mo short for monday) and with the second parameter of the function I can add or backtrack the next day or few days ago with 2 or -1.
For example function test($day, $adder){}; echo test("mo", 2) = we or echo test("mo", -1) = su.

Any idea how to do it?

```
function addDay($day, $adder) {

   $num = (int)$adder;

   $date = array(
   1 => "ma",
   2 => "di",
   3 => "wo",
   4 => "do",
   5 => "vr",
   6 => "za",
   7 => "zo"
   );

};
```

And if its not a number its just gonna print a "error number needed"

Comment: You have `mo` and `su` as day abbreviations which don't appear in your function (I assume a different language).

Comment: @NigelRen It is dutch where ma means maandag (monday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simplier if you had date array starting from index 0.

```
function addDay(string $day, int $adder)
{
    $date = array(
        1 => "ma",
        2 => "di",
        3 => "wo",
        4 => "do",
        5 => "vr",
        6 => "za",
        7 => "zo"
    );

    $no_day = array_search($day, $date);


    return $date[(($no_day - 1 + $adder) % 7) + 1];
}

print(addDay("za", 2)); // 'ma'
print(addDay("za", -2)); // 'do'
print(addDay("za", 7)); // 'za'
```